# How to build regex to match one or the other substring?

Tags: regex

In my project, I can have two sentences like:

```
1) <keyword1> <start_date> <keyword2> <end_date>
2) <keyword1> <end_date>
```

For example:

```
1) "Away 01.09.2000 until 03.09.2000"
2) "Away 01.09.2000"
```

I need to find a match for `<end_date>` against a value I posses - let's call it `<the_date>`. I do not know which version of a sentence I have currently, so I need to cover both cases. If `<the_date>=03.09.2000` I want the match with sentence 1), but if `<the_date>=01.09.2000` I want the match with sentence 2).
I tried this regex (it expects spaces to be removed in the sentence), but it seems not working:

```
\bAway\b([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4}\buntil\b<the_date>|<the_date>(?:(?!\buntil\b))*?)
```

I know there are many similar questions, but I checked a few and none worked for me.

Thank you and appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider a pattern like

```
^Away(?:\s+([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4})\s+until)?\s+01\.09\.2000$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sORnEu/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `Away` - a word
- `(?:\s+([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4})\s+until)?` - an optional occurrence of

  - `\s+([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4})` - 1+ whitespace chars and then Group 1 capturing a sequence of two digits, `.`, two digits, `.` and four digits
  - `\s+until` - 1+ whitespace chars and `until` word
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespace chars
- `01\.09\.2000` - a `01.09.2000` string
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thank you Wiktor. We are almost there. But still there are complications. Usually my sentence is a part of a bigger string and also I am removing all blank chars (spaces, line-feeds), so the sentences may look like below:

Comment: Ok, remove `\s+`, `^` and `$` then.

Comment: Thank you Wiktor for your prompt reply. This is nice and we are almost there. But still there are complications. Usually my sentence is a part of a bigger string, after the keyword1 there might be up to 4 chars  and also I am removing all blank chars (spaces, line-feeds) in the string before matching, so the sentences may look like below:
1) "LongTextBeforeAwaySth01.09.2000until03.09.2000LongTextAfter"
2) "LongTextBeforeAway01.09.2000LongTextAfter"
I changed your regex to:
Away.{0,4}(?:([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4})until)?01\.09\.2000
but then it lost the right match. Please, help.

Comment: @RafalXxx Try appending `(?!until)` to the regex to prevent matching if the `end_date` is immediately followed with `until`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sORnEu/2).

Comment: This works like a charm! Even when I modify it to:
Away[^0-9]{0,4}(?:([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,4})until)?([0-9]{1,2}\.(03|3)\.[0-9]{4})(?!until)
because of date formats that can be DD.MM.YYYY or D.M.Y (or YY). However when I put the number of occurrences of the second year instance all crashes:
Away[^0-9]{0,4}(?:([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,4})until)?([0-9]{1,2}\.(03|3)\.[0-9]{1,4})(?!until). @Wiktor, do you have any idea?