# How to set regex depending on date formats in string?

Tags: regex

This is a new question related to my post:
[How to build regex to match one or the other substring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64006049/how-to-build-regex-to-match-one-or-the-other-substring)

In my project, I can have two sentences like:

```
1) "LongTextBeforeAwaySth01.02.2000until01.03.2000LongTextAfter" 
2) "LongTextBeforeAway01.03.2000LongTextAfter"
```

I need to find a match if a given month (in this case 03-March) is in the rightmost date of the sentence. Because dates may be of different formats (`D.M.Y` / `D.M.YY` / `DD.MM.YYYY`) I construct this regex:

```
Away[^0-9]{0,4}(?:([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,4})until)?([0-9]{1,2}\.(03|3)\.[0-9]{1,4})(?!until)
```

But in the last date-group the number of occurrences indicator `[0-9]{1,4}` makes the regex fails to match. This does not happen if it is only `[0-9]{4}`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DDs0ah/1).

Can you please advice?

Comment: there is no 3rd march date in either of those strings

Comment: what about sth like this: https://regex101.com/r/DDs0ah/2

Comment: I need specific match described in my former post (see comments there as well). I am just having the issue with this year-group matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the negative lookahead at the end allows for a digit to be there, and `[0-9]{1,4}` allowed backtracking to make room for the negative lookahead to succeed.

One option is to assert not `until` or a digit `(?!until|\d)`

Note that you can shorten `(03|3)` to `(0?3)`

```
Away[^0-9]{0,4}(?:([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,4})until)?([0-9]{1,2}\.(0?3)\.[0-9]{1,4})(?!until|\d)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AzLbx2/1)